# Kibana dont create, the indice of my data

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

### What I need?

I need be able of create a index with the data of my logs files.

[image: logstash missing index]

This is **`/etc/logstash/conf.d/apache-01.conf`** (I've tried using `/dev/null` for sincedb and delete **.sincedb_xxx** files from `/var/lib/logstash/plugins/inputs/file` ):

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/test/domainname*"
        start_position => "beginning"
        id => "NEWTRY2"
    }

}

filter {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }
    }
    date {
        match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
    }

    geoip {
        source => "clientip"
    }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts =>  ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "new-index2"
  }
}
```

When I execute the command

```
>> curl http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices
green  open .kibana                     N2gR01kcSMaT74Pj93NqwA 1 0     1 0   4kb   4kb
yellow open metricbeat-6.4.3-2018.11.08 rpBMeq-XS7yGeOd49Wakhw 1 1 14285 0 7.9mb 7.9mb
```

Usually should return a stagged files as ***logstash-2018.11.01***

In the log file, `/var/log/logstash/logstash-plain.log` shows this:

```
[2018-11-08T10:05:15,808][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"6.4.3"}
[2018-11-08T10:05:17,493][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>8, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50}
[2018-11-08T10:05:17,825][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://localhost:9200/]}}
[2018-11-08T10:05:17,834][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Running health check to see if an Elasticsearch connection is working {:healthcheck_url=>http://localhost:9200/, :path=>"/"}
[2018-11-08T10:05:17,997][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://localhost:9200/"}
[2018-11-08T10:05:18,048][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] ES Output version determined {:es_version=>6}
[2018-11-08T10:05:18,051][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>6}
[2018-11-08T10:05:18,075][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["//localhost:9200"]}
[2018-11-08T10:05:18,093][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Using mapping template from {:path=>nil}
[2018-11-08T10:05:18,109][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempting to install template {:manage_template=>{"template"=>"logstash-*", "version"=>60001, "settings"=>{"index.refresh_interval"=>"5s"}, "mappings"=>{"_default_"=>{"dynamic_templates"=>[{"message_field"=>{"path_match"=>"message", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false}}}, {"string_fields"=>{"match"=>"*", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false, "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "ignore_above"=>256}}}}}], "properties"=>{"@timestamp"=>{"type"=>"date"}, "@version"=>{"type"=>"keyword"}, "geoip"=>{"dynamic"=>true, "properties"=>{"ip"=>{"type"=>"ip"}, "location"=>{"type"=>"geo_point"}, "latitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}, "longitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}}}}}}}}
[2018-11-08T10:05:18,212][INFO ][logstash.filters.geoip   ] Using geoip database {:path=>"/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-filter-geoip-5.0.3-java/vendor/GeoLite2-City.mmdb"}
[2018-11-08T10:05:18,440][INFO ][logstash.inputs.file     ] No sincedb_path set, generating one based on the "path" setting {:sincedb_path=>"/var/lib/logstash/plugins/inputs/file/.sincedb_ae5e62ef229d5a1776eda86789823900", :path=>["/test/domainname*"]}
[2018-11-08T10:05:18,528][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline started successfully {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x45edc3cf run>"}
[2018-11-08T10:05:18,566][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
[2018-11-08T10:05:18,576][INFO ][filewatch.observingtail  ] START, creating Discoverer, Watch with file and sincedb collections
[2018-11-08T10:05:18,784][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
```

The **/test/ folder and files** have permission 777 and the owners is the own "logstash" [image: folder permission]

When I execute the command `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/state?pretty'` in it there some lines like this: (I've deleted with `curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/*` the index, because I  want change the logs files and update all)

```
"index-graveyard" : {
  "tombstones" : [
    {
      "index" : {
        "index_name" : "logstash-2018.11.01",
        "index_uuid" : "K8CPa4gYTSO-l4NfnrtTog"
      },
      "delete_date_in_millis" : 1541649663075
    },
    {
      "index" : {
        "index_name" : "logstash-2018.09.01",
        "index_uuid" : "-thB_LnfQlax6tLcS11Srg"
      },
      "delete_date_in_millis" : 1541649663075
    },
    {
      "index" : {
        "index_name" : "logstash-2018.10.31",
        "index_uuid" : "Fm8XcdcTTT2U-Xm1Vw0Gbw"
      },
      "delete_date_in_millis" : 1541649663075
    },
    {
      "index" : {
        "index_name" : "logstash-2018.08.31",
        "index_uuid" : "_FqmkcRNTKOx1oJbnpeyjw"
      },
      "delete_date_in_millis" : 1541649663075
    },
    {
      "index" : {
        "index_name" : "logstash-2018.11.02",
        "index_uuid" : "ZU04EZDaS_eeqD0auI9o5Q"
      },
      "delete_date_in_millis" : 1541649663075
    },
    {
      "index" : {
        "index_name" : ".kibana",
        "index_uuid" : "sZEoKhVlRRy7e8gAAnAEZw"
      },
      "delete_date_in_millis" : 1541653339359
    },
    {
      "index" : {
        "index_name" : "metricbeat-6.4.1-2018.11.06",
        "index_uuid" : "T5UZFMHiRJSMsBjTw40ztA"
      },
```

### What things I've tried?

- Using /dev/null instead of .sincedb default
- Delete .sincedb files
- change the id name within input {}
- change the index name within output {}
- Delete something with `curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/*`
- change files and folder permissions
- killall -9 java
- All related kibana services stop, restart
- Restart the PC
- READ so much topics about this problem T_T

Important: **when I executed it for first time, all work nice, but now not work**

**Note: I am beginner in this topic**
Thanks you.

Comment: Since the curl to `_cat/indices` shows no index, you need to look deeper at logstash's behavior.  Adding the debug output (as suggested below) is a good first step.

Answer (score 1):

When debugging Logstash pipelines using file inputs, I like to simplify it with `stdin` and `stdout`

```
input {
  stdin {}
}
filter {
  ...your filter
}
output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Then

```
cat mylogfile > logstash -f mypipeline.conf
```

The goal is to see if we can get data through. If so, then something is wrong with the file input config or the Elasticsearch output. Mess with each until you figure out which isn't working. Also, ensure you can indeed read the file by doing something like `stat /path/to/your/file`

Generally, the problem with the file input are permissions or sincedb, but sounds like you've been able to eliminate both. In that case, I'd expect `stdin` to succeed.